# LibreOffice Writer preserving fonts in document

Tags: libreoffice, ubuntu-gnome

I'm preparing a paper for my college on command line and shell scripting. I'm using LibreOffice Writer. But, to view it in my college, they'll be using Microsoft Word. I'm using Ubuntu system fonts in the document. Is there a way that I can embed the fonts in my document such that, they remain the same when viewed in Windows?

Comment: Maybe also ask at LibreOffice/OpenOffice forum ? -> https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/index.php

Comment: In my experience, LibreOffice does a decent job opening and saving formats to word formats with baasic features, however, as the documents get more and more complex the formatting starts to change . My advice is to keep your documents as simple as possible and to save them and work with them as .doc or .docx early in the process. I would use only fonts you can expect on a Microsoft computer.

Comment: This is a much more complex problem than you think. The only way to make sure that it's viewed the same way that you formatted it on every viewer's operating system / document viewer, is to export it as a PDF and embed the font. https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/215104/cross-platform-font-incompatibility-across-windows-mac-and-linux/

Answer (score 1):

I STRONGLY ADVISE YOU TEST THIS BY TRANSFERRING THE DOCUMENT ONTO A MICROSOFT COMPUTER ;)

From https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Embedding_Fonts

> Choose **File - Properties - Font tab**
>
> Mark this box to embed document fonts into the document file, for portability between different computer systems. The document with embedded fonts has a larger size and the fonts are used on the target computer for better rendering of the document layout.
>
> Consider embedding fonts when your document use rare or custom fonts not generally available in other computers.

[image]